# Visual Studio 2017 Crashes if `.git` in solution directory

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 Professional is crashing with git.  Even with an empty solution with no projects in it, it still crashes right after starting. If I rename the `.git` directory for example to `_.git`, visual studio doesn't crash.  The workstation I'm on doesn't have access to the internet which I suspect could be associated.

After the crash, I've tried debugging it.  There is one error but I can't be sure the error is related. `system.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. parameter name: path1`

I've tried turning off **Tools** -> **Options** -> **SourceControl** -> **Plug-in Selection** by setting it to **None**. No success.

Any idea on what else could help solve this?

Comment: Post your finding below as an answer, so that you can accept it and end the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The crash was associated with the TGit v5.1.3 Visual Studio plugin. Disabling this plugin has prevented the crash but now the system hangs when the solution is first opened. I still believe this is related to my workstation being disconnected from the internet.